# WebSphere - new servlets in web.xml not added to web_merged.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, websphere, web.xml

When/how does web_merged.xml get generated in WebSphere Portal Server 8.5?

I have a build process that unpacked wps.ear/wps.war, added some servlets to web.xml, re-packed it and re-deployed it.

This worked great in WebSphere 7.0, but in WebSphere 8.5, the new servlets in web.xml never got added to web_merged.xml.  Setting `metadata-complete="true"` solves the problem but isn't always a viable option (what if I really did want to scan classes for annotations?)

Also, note that the servlet spec in web.xml is 3.0.

What may have changed in 8.5?